# White listing groups in azure active directry

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

We would like to enable group expiry for groups in active directory. However for some few sites, we would like to disable this. But in the UI it looks like it is all, or you have to add each group manually. Is there any way to enable for all, but with option to disable some?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***AFAIK, currently there is no option available in Azure Portal UI to enable group expiration policy for All by disabling some groups.***

As you mentioned you have to manually add the groups by choosing **Selected** option.

*If you want to select all and disable some groups in particular, you can raise a feature request to Azure Support to include that option.*

If you don't want to do the above, you can create a **CSV file**  as a workaround.

- Make sure the .csv file should contain a column **`ObjectId`** that includes IDs of Azure AD Groups on which you want to apply the expiration policy.
- Create a expiration policy by choosing **selected** option.
- Make use of above **policy ID** in the PowerShell script and update by importing the above CSV file like below:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$policy = "your_policy_id"
$groups = import-csv ".\your_csv_file.csv"
Foreach ($group in $groups) {
Add-AzureADMSLifecyclePolicyGroup -Id $policy -groupId $group.objectId}
```

**Reference** :

[Set Expiry Policy for Specific Groups · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/clelsdon/0e688a3526e4895c0d6bd63daeed0ad3#file-setaadexpirypolicyselected-ps1)

Comment: That will not handle new sites. But maybe I could make a site script. Do you know if same is possible with azure graph or c# in anyway?